# .net core application can't find the correct appsettings using environment variables

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I have a simple .net core application. It's using `WebApplicationBuilder` to create the instance of the application at runtime.

The code in the `program.cs` looks like this:

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();

builder.WebHost.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.ClearProviders();
    logging.AddConsole();
    logging.AddSerilog(logger);
});
```

My `launchsetting.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:29881",
      "sslPort": 44344
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "MyApp.Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7134;http://localhost:5134",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When running this app using the `MyApp.Api` profile locally, it works. It uses `appsetting.Development.json` and transforms it's json values over `appsetting.json`.

However, when I publish and deploy the application to a server outside of my local environment, it doesn't use the provided `appsetting.CURRENT.json`.

The environment variables are set as follow:

```
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=CURRENT
Environment=DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=CURRENT
```

And I can see the files being deployed to the correct directory.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    2397 Oct 13  2022 appsettings.CURRENT.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    1527 Oct 13  2022 appsettings.json
```

I'm completely out of ideas. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking to use `CreateDefaultBuilder`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0

That one will use `appsettings.{Environment}.json` automatically (more detail on what it does at that link.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest a different approach:

```cs
if(builder.Environment.IsProduction())
{
  builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(
    "appsettings.CURRENT.json",
    optional: false, reloadOnChange: true
  );
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions